# Display a specific block from an image

Tags: css

I have an image (example.png) divided in **n** times **m** blocks, and consider this class:

```css
.myFullImg{
   background: url(example.png);
}
```

I want to create a div in which i show in his background just a specific block:

```html
<div class="myFullImg" style="..."></div>
```

I don't know what to put in `style` above ?

**Example:** the image `image.png` had: `height:150px` and `width:100px`.

Then i have 6x4=24 blocks in this image with `height:25px` and `width:25px`

And i want in a div to display a block from the image `image.png`

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: You want to set a width and height on the div, then adjust the `background-position` property of the background image to match the image you want.

Comment: Thank you for yours contribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the div's `width` and `height` to `25px` and make use of the `background-position` property with negative values in steps of 25 pixels. So in order to show the 6th block (from the top left), you would set the values like this:

```css
.myFullImg{
   background: url("https://placekitten.com/100/150");
   background-position: -25px -25px;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="myFullImg"></div>
```